# Dynamically adding a meta tag on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, meta-tags

```
public void Save(object s, EventArgs e)
{

    HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta() { Name = "DownloadOptions", Content = "noopen" };

    MetaPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(meta);

    string name = "Editor.html";

        //Response.AppendHeader("X-Download-Options", "noopen");
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/SentinelOperationsUI/Editor.html"), true);
    Response.End();
}
```

The meta tag, `<meta name="DownloadOptions" content="noopen" />`, works great in ie7 if i add it manually to the header. But if i try to add it dynamically like this, i get no effect.

What do i need to do to add this meta tag for this download buttons event click? I only want it added to this button. Do i need to remove it in all other download buttons click events?

Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually thought of it, but would it make a difference? Since my placeholder is in the `<head>` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a header that go inside the header of a page, then you append a header that try to load a file, and then you send one html file.

The append header with the attachment file is overwrite and ignore the html header that you try to set before, but also the html file that you send with the writeFile is direct send to the browser, and the **response.End** stop all other writing, including the **HtmlMeta** that you have add before.

Even if you remove the .End() the header is going to be written after all data that you send and also have no meaning.

Comment: Ok, i tried a jquery solution that seems to be working. Adding/removing the meta tag when clicking on the different download buttons. Does it sound like an ok solution?

Comment: @Johan if its work, its ok. To me is not sounds ok because the header is readed only when the page load, when you make post the page header is not re-readed by the browser until the page is come back and in your case you do not resend the html header again. Why not use a handler to send the file with a direct link ?

Comment: Ok, not sure if im following you on the last part. Do you mean that i should create the file in a generic handler?

Comment: @Johan Yes create the file in a generic handler. The headers that you may confuse is two type. One that is send on browser request and actions take before the ask of the html page, and the one that is written on html page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, ill look in to that if my jquery solution stops working :-)